# How to execute Javascript following a form submission

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an Asp.Net Core app, and I'm submitting a form like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "Action", FormMethod.Post)
{
    <button type="submit">RunMyMethod</button>                    
}
```

When the call to MyMethod has finished (successfully), I want to execute a peice of JS code, for example:

```
@section Scripts {
    function functionWorked() {
        alert('This worked!');
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  I was thinking there may be some form of callback option for the `BeginForm` (but I can't see one).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the controller method handling the form post returns a view model. Extend that view model by a boolean property `RenderMyScript` that indicates that your script should be included. Set it to true.

Then, check for the boolean in the view:

```
@if (Model.RenderMyScript)
{
  @section Scripts {
      function functionWorked() {
          alert('This worked!');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you detect when the post finished, though?

Comment: I assume that your page reloads for the post. If the code in your controller runs synchronously (per default), the post is finished before rendering the view. So setting RenderMyScript to true will happen after the post is finished and before the view is shown

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that when the form is submitted, your page was switched away. So you can never execute any javascript on it after the form successfully submitted.

However, you can override the submit event of your form.

If the user submits the form:

- Prevent the browser to switch page.
- Submit the data on our own instead.
- Trigger your success method

Just like this: (The following javascript requires jQuery)

```js
@section Scripts {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                   alert('This worked!');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Unknown error!');
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert you form to ajax based, for handling onsuccess events.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Action", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess ="onSuccess" }))
{
    <button type="submit">RunMyMethod</button>                    
}
```

and Javascript/Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(result) {
        alert("Success")
    }
</script>
```